# Array declaration by variable value

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

```
void Group::load(){
int temp[xxx];
for(int i=0;i<xxx;i++) temp[i]=i+13;
for(int i=0;i<xxx;i++) cout<<temp[i]<<" ";
}
```

I have a class named Group where I have declared a variable xxx. I initialize this variable through the constructor. In the function above, this code works as expected. My question is How can I do the same thing by declaring temp array in the Class definition where xxx variable is obtained through the base class. How can I do this or something similar to this. It seems I have to dynamically allocate arrays because I want to load data from text files and fill arrays based on their sizes.

Comment: You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you need an array of unknown size. The usage would be `std::vector<int> temp{xxx};`.

Comment: if `int temp[xxx];` works with a `xxx` that you initialized in the constructor then this is only due to a non-standard compiler extension. It is discouraged to use it because in c++ we have better ways to declare dynamically sized arrays (aka `std::vector`) and because it is not standard c++

Answer (score 1):

You should use a std::vector (from the standard library). You can initialize it in the constructor to the base class:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(int size) : data{size} {}
  protected:
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```